# How can i have a loop for the name until it is correct?

Tags: python

```
import re
username = input("Enter your name to start the test: ")
#Prompting the user to input their name

valid = re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$",username)
#A validation of letters only being used

if not valid:
    print("Error! Letters only!")
    username = input("Enter your name: ")
```

Comment: read the doc for `while`

Comment: You're accepting an empty string as a valid username?

Answer (score 0):

why not use a while loop with your condition. Something like this, you fill in the details:

```
username = input("Enter your name to start the test: ")
while not re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$",username):
    print("Error! Letters only!")
    username = input("Enter your name: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

valid = False

while not valid:
    username = input("Enter your name to start the test: ")
    valid = re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", username)

    if not valid:
        print("Error! Letters only!")
```